# How to prevent overfitting in a CNN model with <500 data?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I was trying to build a CNN model based on classifying folk dances of India. The problem is that the dataset I have is very less. I tried Data Augmentation, using dropouts, regularizers and varying the optimizer but the model still overfits (around 85% train acc. and 52% test acc.). What should I improve/change in this model to prevent overfitting? I am providing the github link which contains the notebook as well as the dataset.
https://github.com/C3Suryansu/Traditional-Dance-Classification

Comment: Did you try other classifiers? Why did you choose CNN?

Comment: A way I used to use is use `ImageDataGenerator()`, this Method with couples of variable can bring you more and more Image than you have. You can find example [**here**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator)

Comment: @ypnos Few reasons, mainly:-
1 - I am quite new to Image recongnition and such tasks, and was trying to implement a CNN to get the intuition behind it as how the structure is built and how various conditions like overfitting/underfitting can be prevented.
2- The task I was attempting was part of a challenge on hackerearth.com and it was a deep learning challenge, so I attempted using a CNN.
By other classifiers you mean Random Forest and such?

Comment: @dungxibo123 I used ImageDataGenerator(), even added more factors like vertical_flip,rotation angle, and other such features, yet wasn't able to solve the overfitting problem, plus including dropout kinda decreased the accuracy too along with the overfitting problem.

Comment: Okay, hmm, let see, the easiest way is to collect more data, I'm also trainning CNNs with just around 300 images, and It work very well. And when I compare my dataset with others(commonly 1000 - 1000000 images) I saw that although my dataset is kinda small but I have validation data set around 84%, if you have fewer than 50 images, I think you must find more and more data. Good luck

Comment: @dungxibo123 Oh, can you share the type of network and hyperparameters you are using?